# Unexpected EOF in prolog in Camel Xslt when input is InputStreamCache

Tags: apache-camel, saxon

Since version 3.17, Camel have automatic conversion to Stream Caches. When upgrading (from version 3.14 to version 4.0.2) we face a strange problem.

We use the Saxon Xslt component to transform Xml data. Previously the Exchange Input was of type byte[], now it is of type InputStreamCache. This is as expected and should work without any changes. But when the Exchange is transformed we get:

`net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Error reported by XML parser: Unexpected EOF in prolog`

which indicates that the transformation is running on empty input. I.e. that the InputStreamCache is empty (which it is not).

For reference here is the full stack trace of the exception:

```
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Error reported by XML parser: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]
    at net.sf.saxon.pull.StaxBridge.next(StaxBridge.java:205)
    at net.sf.saxon.pull.PullFilter.next(PullFilter.java:98)
    at net.sf.saxon.pull.PullPushTee.next(PullPushTee.java:73)
    at net.sf.saxon.pull.PullConsumer.consume(PullConsumer.java:42)
    at net.sf.saxon.pull.PullPushCopier.copy(PullPushCopier.java:44)
    at net.sf.saxon.pull.PullSource.deliver(PullSource.java:95)
    at net.sf.saxon.pull.ActiveStAXSource.deliver(ActiveStAXSource.java:61)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.send(Sender.java:104)
    at net.sf.saxon.Controller.makeSourceTree(Controller.java:1306)
    at net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltTransformer.transform(XsltTransformer.java:342)
    at net.sf.saxon.jaxp.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:75)
    at org.apache.camel.component.xslt.XsltBuilder.process(XsltBuilder.java:123)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ProcessorEndpoint.onExchange(ProcessorEndpoint.java:93)
    at org.apache.camel.component.xslt.XsltEndpoint.onExchange(XsltEndpoint.java:120)
```

When we switch back to the old functionality by setting

`camelContext.setStreamCaching(false);`

everything works as expected.

- Did we miss some configuration option in Camel to make this work?
- How can we pinpoint the root cause for the exception?
- Is there an example or test anywhere that verifies that Saxon Xslt works with InputStreamCache as input?

After digging some more, here are a few comments:

As it turns out we were doing `String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);` somewhere in the route before this.

For some reason there is a problem with the InputStreamCache when doing this. We can see that the underlying "pos" of the Stream is updated to the end of the stream. So at some point when the Stream is copied into StaxSource, it copies from "pos" and to the end. And as we are already at the end, nothing is copied into the StaxSource.

We found that this is helping

`String inBody = MessageHelper.extractBodyAsString(exchange.getIn());`

as well as
`MessageHelper.resetStreamCache(exchange.getIn());`

However, not sure if this is how the InputStreamCache is supposed to work? The Camel documentation on the subject is rather cursory.

Comment: Do you know what kind of Source object is actually being passed to Saxon's transform() method, or is this all "under the hood" in Camel?

Comment: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/release/4.0.3/components/camel-xslt-saxon/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/xslt/saxon/SaxonXmlSourceHandlerFactoryImpl.java and https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/release/4.0.3/components/camel-xslt/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/xslt/XsltBuilder.java#L123 and https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/main/components/camel-xslt/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/xslt/XmlSourceHandlerFactoryImpl.java#L59 might be relevant.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I added some more info in the questions.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected, as if you write you own code to read the body as String with the code line you did. And its streaming based, then you need to reset the stream afterwards. This happens also automatic in the routing engine between EIPs, so if you do this in a processor before calling the next EIP that does the XSLT transformation then Camel routing engine should have reset it automatic.